# max price with LINQ and Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have `GenericRepository` with a method

```
public virtual IEnumerable<tentity> Get(
Expression<func<tentity, bool="">> filter = null,
Func<iqueryable<tentity>, IOrderedQueryable<tentity>> orderBy = null,
string includeProperties = "")
{
  IQueryable<tentity> query = dbSet;
  if (filter != null)
  {
    query = query.Where(filter);
  }
  foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
      (new char[] { ’,’ }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  {
    query = query.Include(includeProperty);
  }
  if (orderBy != null)
  {
    return orderBy(query).ToList();
  }
  else
  {
    return query.ToList();
  }
}
```

For example, I get products:

```
var products = _database.ProductRepository.Get(
filter: d => d.Price == price.Value,
orderBy:
q => q.OrderBy(d => d.Name));
```

How can I get products with a Max Price? (maybe like `d.Max(d => d.Price)`)

Answer (score 1):

Try with LINQ:

```
var product = from p in products
              where p.Price == products.Max(s => s.Price)
              select p;
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. But i have to get all products before filtering. Do we have another way with better LINQ selection ?

Comment: I didn't get it. Are you trying to filter without a list? You could see if there's a filter as arg and return a list with one element (the filtered one).